# Snowflake stored procedure to download data from a website

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to programmatically download data from a public website that offers a static url to download a csv, which is updated weekly.

My thought process involves using a stored procedure (with external network access) to download the file to an internal stage, and then construct a table/view on top of these files.  I'd then have a task automate the process to run weekly to automatically download new files.

I've put together the following procedure, which is able to access the file stream (so the external access seems to work), but then fails when I try to write to internal stage.

```
create or replace procedure download_data(file_url string, dest_stage string, dest_filename string)
returns variant
language python
runtime_version = 3.11
packages = ('snowflake-snowpark-python', 'urllib3')
external_access_integrations = (my_access_integration)
handler = 'main'
execute as caller
as
$$

from snowflake.snowpark import FileOperation

import urllib3
import os


def main(session, file_url, dest_stage, dest_filename):
    
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    resp = http.request('GET', file_url, preload_content = False,)

    print(resp.read(10)) # this works!
    
    sf = FileOperation(session)
    sf.put_stream(
        input_stream = resp,
        stage_location = os.path.join(dest_stage, dest_filename),
        auto_compress = False,
    )

    return f'File from ({file_url}) landed in stage {dest_stage} with name {dest_filename}'
    
$$
;
```

The error I get states:  `io.UnsupportedOperation: File or stream is not seekable.`

Am I using the file stream incorrectly, or does the `put_stream` method not yet support this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the response into a seekable stream with:

```py
content_bytes = response.data 
seekable_stream = io.BytesIO(content_bytes)
```

Make sure beforehand that `response.status == 200`.

Comment: I wound up using the `requests` library, but your code still worked -- minor change `content_bytes = response.content` in that case.  Thanks for all your support on Snowflake matters!

Comment: Thanks for the update and for posting the question, I got to learn too in the process :)

Comment: One more comment -- this works well for small files (< 1mb) but its struggling with larger files (> ~1gb).  It hangs when creating the `BytesIO` object ... This seems like an `io` problem to figure out, and I'm looking into it, but wondering if you might be familiar with a solution off the bat?

Comment: That seems like an interesting question to research, would you open a new one with that constrain?